# Problem reinstalling GRUB

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub

I have a PC that dual-boots Ubuntu and Windows Vista. I recently reinstalled Windows Vista after some problems and now the bootloader's gone.

I've been trying to follow [this Ubuntu community guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) but it's not working. I have Grub Legacy according to the first part (I installed Ubuntu 9.04 originally then upgraded).

From the 9.04 LiveCD, I ran this:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/disk /dev/sda5
```

`sda5` is the Ubuntu partition. I get this output:

```
grub-probe: error: Cannot open `/boot/grub/device.map`
[: 494: =: unexpected operator
Installing GRUB to /dev/sda5 as (hd0,4)...
Installation finished.No errors reported.
This is the contents...(etc)

(hd0)   /dev/sda
```

In the bit below, when I run `setup (hd0)` I get an error, "**Error 17: Cannot mount selected partition**"

Little help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, the line `root (hd0,0)` should have been `root (hd0,4)` since that is what was output from the earlier command.

Everything sorted.

Comment: You should mark your answer as an answer to the question.